# How UIControlEvent are stored into a UIControl instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture

I'm working on a class similar to `UIControl` and I would replicate some of its behaviours.

I wonder how Apple has implemented the `UIControl` structure that stores the relations between actions, targets and `UIControlEvents`.

Looking at the `UIControl` class I saw that `UIControlEvents` [(documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEvents) defines a list of options that we can use to create a bit mask.

In my opinion there is something like a dictionary that uses as keys the event type and stores  structure with the target and selector as value.

I can create something similar and probably it works :P but I'd like to have your opinions to 
be sure to move head straight for the right direction.

For example... the first big doubt that I have is how can I convert a `UIControlEvent` type into a valid key for a dictionary? (or any other structure if you think that the dictionary is not the solution) have I to convert it to an NSString??? It seems a buggy solution.